# Indentation and smart indent in ScintillaNET

Tags: c#, .net, indentation, scintilla

Can someone describe me how to make indentation work in Scintilla.net?

```
this.scintilla1.Indentation.SmartIndentType = ScintillaNet.SmartIndent.Simple;
```

I'm confused on what needs to be done to get it to work. Can someone describe what event handlers need to be implemented to get indentation to work?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set `Indentation.IndentWidth` to `8`, if `Indentation.TabWidth` is also set to `8`.

Of cource `Indentation.SmartIndentType` must still be set to `Simple`.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking to add indentation - note ScintillaNET 3.x+ does not have indentation built into the base code. At least, not as of 3.6.3.

See [this message for an example of sending indentation commands directly to Scintilla](https://gist.github.com/Ahmad45123/f2910192987a73a52ab4).

See [this message with information from jacobslusser (the maintainer of ScintillaNET) for information about a simple indentation system in ScintillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/issues/35).