# Indentation and smart indent in wxStyledTextCtrl (Scintilla)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, scintilla, wxstyledtextctrl

Does anyone know how to get smart indentation working with the wxStyledTextCtrl in C++?

I have been trying various variations on the following without apparent success:

```
_textEd->SetProperty(wxT("indentation.smartindenttype"), wxT("indentation:simple"));
_textEd->SetProperty(wxT("indentation.indentwidth"), wxT("4"));
_textEd->SetProperty(wxT("indentation.tabwidth"), wxT("4"));
_textEd->SetProperty("spell.mistake.indicator", "style:squigglelow");
```

Note: [Indentation and smart indent in ScintillaNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374206/indentation-and-smart-indent-in-scintillanet) covers this issue for .NET.

Comment: does stc sample works for you? What is you wx version and OS/toolkit?

Answer (score 2):

The SetProperty method is used to add additional settings for a lexer.  It's usually used for settings related to code folding.  It's not used to set properties for the control itself.  For setting properties of the wxStyledTextCtrl, you probably want to use the [standard methods](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html). For example, I guess the lines:

```
_textEd->SetProperty(wxT("indentation.indentwidth"), wxT("4"));
_textEd->SetProperty(wxT("indentation.tabwidth"), wxT("4"));
```

would probably be something like:

```
_textEd->SetIndent(4);
_textEd->SetTabWidth(4);
```

For '_textEd->SetProperty(wxT("indentation.smartindenttype"), wxT("indentation:simple"));', I have no clue what smartindenttype is.  Is that maybe an extension that was added to scintilla.net?  If you can describe what that setting does in .net, I might be able to help accomplish the same thing with other method calls.

Similarly, I don't think the line '_textEd->SetProperty("spell.mistake.indicator", "style:squigglelow");' has any analogue with wxStyledTextCtrl.  None of the included lexers have a spell checker.